# who to make variables during run-time (in c++ )

Tags: c++

I want to let the user of my program define variables ,  then makes mathematical operation on them like "define a:integer , b:double" then "print a*b"

I found that I can use "boost any" but I need the type of the variable be dynamically recognized because want to use variable(objects) of classes ....
so  I want to use the operation (+ * ...) defined in that class

It's like I want to make a container of different types but when I use items in this container
later I use operation defined for this item type !

thanks in advance

Comment: Is it an homework? If not, I'd not use C++ for this task

Comment: Why C++? Why not a language that already offers dynamic typing and runtime evaluation?

Comment: so what language do you suggest guys ?

Comment: I'd go with Javascript. Bonus feature - works in your browser.

Comment: but I need to make .exe file of the program , yes it's a homework

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do it is using [Polymorphism in C++](http://www.cs.bu.edu/teaching/cpp/polymorphism/intro/)

Answer (score 2):

That would not be possible, because when C++ compiles your code, it loses much of the information that is in your code, like function names and variable types. It knows them for the moment of compilation, and it produces machine codes that do what your code says, but in the end it's all discarded. (OK, not exactly true, but close to that).

So if you want to evaluate expressions that the user has entered, you'll need to do a lot of parsing in your own code. Perhaps another, dynamic language which has the "eval" statement would be more of use here?

**Added:** Suggested language: Javascript. Because you can work it in your browser on whatever platform you like.

Answer (score 1):

From the comments:

> Why C++? Why not a language that already offers dynamic typing and runtime evaluation? –
>
> so what language do you suggest guys ?

[Python](http://python.org/).

Comment: +1 on that. You could also create a .exe from a Python script

Answer (score 1):

If you must use c++, i'd suggest embedding a dynamic scripting language. Python, Lua and Javascript all come to mind.

You'd be able to do everything you want to do AND still compile the code to be an .exe.

Comment: I already tried this but I had the problem that I need to use the operations defined for each type ( I made my class and I want to use it ) thanks

Comment: Adding some code of exactly what you're trying to do would probably help you more than just giving a small/simple description.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are expected to create and update some symbol table that is being updated when a define command is entered and consulted during an arithmetic operation. Generally you do not need to store a value of any type, you may assume a finite set of possible value types (integer, real etc.) and represent it in the table. Personally I would create a class with specific operation for every value type that is derived from the common base to which a reference would be stored in the symbol table.